# Apple のレビューにて iOS アプリの Facebook ログインができない

Tags: ios, facebook, appstore-approval, parse.com

TestFlight の外部テストでは問題なく Facebook ログインができているのにも関わらず、Apple のレビューでログインができず、何度も Reject となってしまいます。

Apple からの回答は下記の通り。

> We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on
>   iPad running iOS 8.1.1 and iPhone 5s running iOS 8.1.1, on both Wi-Fi
>   and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store
>   Review Guidelines.
>
> We are still unable to log into your app with Facebook. We are
>   presented with the error message 'ユーザーはこのアプリケーションを見ることを許可されていません。:
>   開発者の設定により、ユーザーはこのアプリケーションを見ることを許可されていません。'

- バックエンドに Parse を使用。
- 手元では、TestFlight の内部テスター版、外部テスター版ともに問題なく動作している。
- Facebook のアプリ設定のステータスは「This app is public and available to all users」となっている。
- Facebook の Approved Items は email, public_profile, user_friends で、アプリで指定しているものは、public_profile, user_friends のみ。
- Facebook の Country Restricted は NO（制限なし）に設定されている。

同様の問題を解決された方、解決法やヒントを頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

このエラーメッセージは、英語では以下になるようです<sup>1</sup>:

> User is not allowed to see the application.: The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration.

これで検索するといくつか原因が出てきます:

- Apple側のレビュワーがFacebookのテスト用アカウントでログインしようとしていた<sup>2, 3</sup>

  - → Appleにテスト用アカウントを使わずにテストするように言う
- レビュワーのFacebookアカウントがブロックされていた<sup>3</sup>
- Facebookアプリの設定でNamespaceを設定していなかった<sup>3</sup>
- FacebookアプリのシークレットIDがParseの設定からなぜか消えていた<sup>3</sup>

外部テスターで問題が出ていないということはレビュワーが使っているアカウントの問題かもしれません。

---

<sup>1</sup> [Facebookの公式翻訳アプリ](https://www.facebook.com/help/100117036792266)で、[日本語のエラーメッセージを検索](https://www.facebook.com/help/100117036792266)しました。  
<sup>2</sup> [Error With Facebook Login Using Test Users](http://samwize.com/2014/07/23/error-with-facebook-login-using-test-users/)  
<sup>3</sup> [Facebook login error “User is not allowed to see the application.”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24960053/20226)

Comment: 有用な回答ありがとうございます！こちらで用意したテストアカウントでの再テストをリクエストしてみました。

Comment: 結局、提供したアカウントで問題なくログインできたらしく、めでたく Ready for sale となりました。改めてありがとうございました！